# NullReferenceException with an instance of a class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an instance of a class and it is null, how can I solve this?

It is a monobehavior assigned to an object.

```
static Myclass instance = GetComponent<Myclass>()
```

Comment: What's the reason for the downvote? The question seems fairly clear, even if the subject line may be a bit ill-chosen.

Comment: that code shouldn't even compile at all ... you can not use instance methods to initialize a field on declaration because this would happen in a static context .. even less if it is about a static field ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @derHugo: While that is true, that seems at best tangential to the problem in focus (which appears to be the behaviour of `GetComponent`) and the most appropriate reaction would probably be a comment asking for clarification rather than a comment-less downvote. YMMV.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I think downvotes are fully understandable if the posted code doesn't even compile .. so how should we even know what exactly OP is asking? [`GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponent.html) is well documented and any misbehaviour most probably a user mistake .. which again we can't provide any helpful answer for if we don't even see the actual usage ..

Answer (score 1):

If `GetComponent` returns `null`, then that is because there is no component of the specified type attached to your `GameObject`. From the [`GetComponent` docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) (emphasis by myself):

> Returns the component of Type `type` if the game object has one attached, **null if it doesn't.**

In other words, `GetComponent` will not automatically create the component if none is found.

Once you have discovered that there is no component of the specified type available, you can use the [`AddComponent<T>` method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html) to create one instead.